# VueJS: using variable in href

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an item.channelId that I have like to use in href.  It should achieve something like this:

```
          <a :href="https://youtube.com/${item.channelId}">{{
            item.channelTitle
          }}</a>
```

How can I put item.channelId into href?

Comment: use this syntax: `:href="\`https://youtube.com/${item.channelId}\`"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use backtick to escabe variable inside of a string like this

```
<a :href="`https://youtube.com/${item.channelId}`">
    {{item.channelTitle}}
</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using

```
 <a :href="'https://youtube.com/'+item.channelId">{{item.channelTitle}}</a>
```

In the above example the property value `href` is treated as the string sum of `'https://youtube.com/'` and the value in the variable `item.channelId`

If you want to make use of template literals, try

```
<a :href="`https://youtube.com/${item.channelId}`">{{item.channelTitle}}</a>
```

In case of [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#:%7E:text=Template%20literals%20are%20string%20literals,editions%20of%20the%20ES2015%20specification.), the variable values are written inside `${}` syntax and the entire string will be enclosed inside backticks (` `)

Answer (score 1):

It should be:`` "`https://youtube.com/${item.channelId}`" `` with backticks.

You can check here: [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

I think you are trying to use Template Literals. You should surround your string with backticks for it to work and not just `""`.

Everything inside backticks will be considered a string aside from anything with `${variable-name}` will be considered a variable.